# Number changes in all row of array

Tags: python

I created a 4x5 2D array using python, and when I wanted to change a number inside it, it automatically changes the number in every row

```
rows,cols = (4,5)
arr = [[0]*cols]*rows
print (arr)
```

And this is how the output shows

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

After I created the array, I decide to change a number in the first row

```
arr[0][2] = 3
print(arr)
```

But it appears like this

```
[[0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0]]
```

I checked with it and I still can't find any problem in it. May someone help me with it?

Comment: check shallow copy and deep copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Multiplying' the list copies the value references repeatedly - which is fine for primitives but not so much for lists, like you've seen. If you want different instances of the list, you could use list comprehension:

```
rows, cols = (4, 5)
arr = [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
arr[0][2] = 3
print(arr) # [[0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```